# How to convert a binary string into an ASCII string?

Tags: c++, ascii, stringstream

I am trying to convert a string of binary to a readable ASCII string. I am able to successfully output the converted string to the console as readable text but when I try to output it to a file, it outputs it as non-English characters.

```
void toHexx(string& in, ofstream& outFile)
{
   int temp[8]={0};
   char theChar[8];
   stringstream ss;

   for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
      if(in.at(0)=='1')
         temp[i]+=128;
      if(in.at(1)=='1')
         temp[i]+=64;
      if(in.at(2)=='1')
         temp[i]+=32;
      if(in.at(3)=='1')
         temp[i]+=16;  
      if(in.at(4)=='1')
         temp[i]+=8;
      if(in.at(5)=='1')
         temp[i]+=4;
      if(in.at(6)=='1')
         temp[i]+=2;
      if(in.at(7)=='1')
         temp[i]+=1;

      in.erase(0,8);

       theChar[i]=(char) temp[i];

       ss << theChar[i];

   }

    cout << ss.str();
    outFile << ss.str();
}
```

Comment: There is no hex conversion here, or conversion to ASCII either. All you are doing is converting ASCII-coded binary to binary, displaying it in decimal, and writing the binary to a file.

Comment: If your input is string of '0' and '1' - easiest way to convert to number is by using bitset constructor from string, and then extract number by http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong

Answer (score 0):

What your'e doing here is not hex conversion (hex is a different way of interpreting and presenting the data. You're storing the information in an integer array where each cell represents a bit.
First - if you expect a byte, which can hold a value up to 255, why would you declare temp as int[8] ? Instead, you could hold that in 'char'. 
In addition, you have several more problems, with type-selection for your parameters and some logic problems.
I've modified your function a little to perform what I think you've wanted, look at the diff and try to see where you mistaken.
Good luck!

```
void binToChar(const std::string& in)
{
    char temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if ('1' == in.at(i)) {
            temp += pow(2, 7 - i);
        }
    }

    std::cout << temp;
}
```